# Finding the Fourier series of $f(x)=\sin x \cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

Let us have $f(x)=\sin x \cos^2x$. We need to get the Fourier-series of this.

Should we make $f(x)$ nicer using the known identities between $\sin, \cos$? I tried using, that $\cos^2x=\frac12 + \frac12 \cos(2x)$.

How should I move forward, and what is the general approach for this kind of tasks? :)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your interval you need the series over?

Comment: The task simply says to get the Fourier series of $f$, and it says in (), that I need to write it as the sum of trigonometric polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
f(x)=\sin x \cos^2x=\frac12\sin(2x)\cdot\cos x=\frac14\left(\sin(3x)+\sin(x)\right)
$$ which is clearly a Fourier series over $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: How did you get $\sin x \cos^2 x= \frac12 \sin(2x) \cos x$ ? :)

Comment: By using first $\sin(2x)=2\cos x \sin x$ then $\sin a \sin b=\frac12(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b))$ with $a=2x$ and $b=x$.

Comment: $sin(2x)=2sin(x)cos(x)$

Comment: @Raquan You are welcome.